# Caracteres Invisiveis

Tags: java

Montando um exemplo web, ao receber da aplicação uma string para a projeção no html, percebi uma incoerência. Gostaria de obter ajuda quanto a isso.

Em um dos momentos da criação da página tenho um tratamento do objeto a ser persistido, e o tratamento é esse:

```
   //sobrenome - apenas caracteres
   String s = v.getSobrenome();
   if(s.isEmpty()||!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", s))
      v.setSobrenome("!INVALIDO!");
```

O único problema é que apareceu, magicamente, um caracter invalido (está entre o O de INVALIDO e a exclamação), que não ocupa espaço na apresentação, mas é contável pelo cursor do teclado ("setinhas").

Ao tentar entrar na pasta da classe para pega-la do meu trabalho e levar pra casa para analisar, acabei entrando no .java pelo navegador (Firefox) e me deparei com isso:

```
   //sobrenome - apenas caracteres
   String s = v.getSobrenome();
   if(s.isEmpty()||!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", s))
      v.setSobrenome("!INVALIDOÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„!Âƒ");
```

Eu não tenho nenhum lugar para esse caracter ter "aparecido" na classe.

O bom é que apagando resolveria o problema, mas gostaria de saber se alguém já se deparou com ele, já tratou e sabe sua origem.

**EDIÇÃO**

Tá começando a ficar complicado para mim.
Eu copiei o caracter e coloquei em uma classe limpa, e ao tentar salvar o Eclipse me gerou um erro, dizendo ser impossível salvar em um formato de caracteres chamado "Cp1252".

Comment: Qual o charset to arquivo? Qual o charset detectado pelo firefox? Existem vários caracteres de controle invisíveis como `\u200b`, `\u200e`, e `\u200f`, mas eu não tenho ideia sobre como você conseguiu inserir um deles manualmente pelo seu editor.

Comment: Pelo eclipse está como UTF-8, pelo navegador não consegui identificar, mas acredito que está com o mesmo encoding.

Comment: Eu acredito que o motivo seja algum "copia-cola" de outra parte do código, onde utilizei um padrão do mapa de caracteres do próprio Windows 7. Mas era um padrão que já tinha utilizado e não havia esse tipo de conflito e falha de interpretação.

Comment: Acho que já está bem explicado o que aconteceu, o que falta então é "como resolver?"... Eu sugiro fazer o seguinte: 1) Crie uma classe "limpa", como você fez; 2) Copie todo o código até o início da string "!INVALIDO!" (não copie a string em si); 3) Copie todo código **depois** da string (de novo, não copie a string); 4) Digite a string manualmente. Isso deve produzir um código sem caracteres fantasma. Ao salvar, confira a codificação (você diz que pelo eclipse está como UTF-8, mas ao salvar ele reclama de erro relacionado ao Cp1252... verifique a codificação real sendo usada no seu projeto).

Comment: Fazendo como sugerido, não há o erro de formato Cp1252,  ele salva e funciona normalmente.

Comment: Parece que meu eclipse agora reconhece o padrão Cp1252, e se eu defino ele como sendo a codificação, ele apresenta os `Â„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„ÂƒÂ„` no meio da string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas pesquisas, encontrei que o padrão "CP1252" é o padrão default do Windows, também conhecido como "Windows-1252" ou ANSI.

Ao utilizar o mapa de caracteres para outro padrão do meu código, o caracter deve ter quebrado ou então copiado algum caracter de controle,gerando esse padrão estranho de caracter fantasma.

Pelo visto o "CP1252" é também o default de alguns IDEs, dentre eles o Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, este tipo de erro acontece com frequência e eu o batizei de `Caracterer Fantasma`.

Depois de observações, concluí que este problema acontece quando os desenvolvedores trocam **trechos de código através de comunicadores instantâneos**;

Comment: neo, não tem nenhuma melhor explicação quanto a isso?

Comment: Não tenho Gustavo. Apenas tenho o que observei e não fui a fundo no assunto pois não julgo necessário. Se o código está está escrito certo mas não funciona, a regra é remover os espaços e digitá-los novamente.

Comment: Colar código do console do Chrome ou mesmo do jsfiddle também pode causar isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal